# VM Ware show desktop instead windows 8 start screen when switching

Tags: windows-8, vmware-fusion

I'm on Macbook Pro with Windows 8 installed on VM Ware Fusion (version 5.0.3). I always run W8 in full screen mode.

When I am in Apple and I want to switch to W8 (using apple key, arrow right) I always see the W8 start screen. I find this very, very annoying. Is it possible to just show my desktop instead of the start screen?

Edit:

I Always have this behavior. When in W8 and I go to Apple using apple key + arrow left and then immediate go back to W8 using apple key + arrow right, I always get the W8 start screen. I don't see the window as when I left W8.

Comment: Please indicate what version of VMWare Fusion.  Sounds like Windows is simply locking the user because of inactivity.  Please revise your question to clarify if this always happens or not

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated my post

Comment: I don't have the feature list of VMWare Fusion 5 infront of me, i know that the new version of Fusion, has better Windows 8 capabilities.  I can tell you that even WMWare Workstation 9 did this on Windows.

Comment: I don't know much about VMare, but what is Workstation 9?

Comment: This is probably because VMWare translates the Apple key as Windows key and that one naturally pops up Modern UI. You'll either have to change VMWare to accept a different key combination to switch between systems or find some software that lets you switch the Windows key functionality to a different key or just live with it.

Comment: @user253270 - Windows version of VMWare Fusion

Comment: @Zerobinary99 I think you're right. I've changed the key combination and it seems to work now. Can you poast an answer with your solution so I can mark this question as answered and give you the credits for it?

Comment: @user253270 You're very welcome and thanks for wanting to give me credit. I'll post an answer asap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare translates the Apple key as Windows key and that one naturally pops up Modern UI. You can either change VMWare to accept a different key combination to switch between systems or find some software that lets you switch the Windows key functionality to a different key.